# Wrap divs from div parent

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```html
<div class="superdiv">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap all `.superdiv` children divs into a div called `<div class="subdiv"></div>`

How can I make that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`.wrapInner()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/):

```
$('.superdiv').wrapInner('<div class="subdiv"></div>');
```

You could also use the [`.wrapAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) on the children elements:

```
$('.superdiv').children().wrapAll('<div class="subdiv"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
$(".superdiv > div").wrapAll("<div class='subdiv'/>");
```